# D3 - trying to nest based on element name instead of value

Tags: d3.js

I'm not sure if this is possible or not, but I'm try to create a d3.nest object with the key being an element name instead of that element's value.  This is to be used in a stacked area chart.

Here is the sample raw data:

```
{
        "_id" : {
                "month" : 2,
                "day" : 26,
                "year" : 2014
        },
        "total" : 34492,
        "failed" : 1,
        "skipped" : 0
}
```

I'd like to create a nest object based on the total, failed and skipped element names, not their values (i.e.: not the numbers).

The resulting nest object would be something like:

```
[
    {
        key: "total",
        values: [
            {
                "date": "2014-02-26T05:00:00.000Z",
                "count": 34492
            },
            {
                "date": "2014-02-27T05:00:00.000Z",
                "count": 34495
            } 
        ]
    },
    {
        key: "failed",
        values: [
            {
                "date": "2014-02-26T05:00:00.000Z",
                "count": 1
            },
            {
                "date": "2014-02-27T05:00:00.000Z",
                "count": 0
            } 
        ]
    }
]
```

I have some control over the layout of the original data so I have tried adding the total, failed and skipped elements under a status object, but that is not working either.

Here is some code I am working with:

```
data.result.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = new Date(d._id.year, d._id.month-1, d._id.day);
    d.status = {
        "total": d.total,
        "failed": d.failed,
        "skipped": d.skipped
    };
});

var nested = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.status; })
    //.key(function(d) { return d.total; })
    //.key(function(d) { return d.failed; })
    //.key(function(d) { return d.skipped; })
    .entries(data.result);
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a job for `d3.nest`, but it certainly can be done.

A nesting function is used when you have a long array that you want to split into many sub-arrays according to a grouping variable (or multiple nested groups).  Each element in the original array only shows up in one of the sub-arrays.

What you want is to have the same array of data objects repeated three times, each time with a different value extracted.

Start with the original step to parse the Date values:

```
data.result.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = new Date(d._id.year, d._id.month-1, d._id.day);
});
```

Then create an array of the different status types that you want to have as separate data series.  You could create this array from the data by looking at the object keys, but I'm assuming here that you know what the options should be:

```
var statusTypes = ["total", "failed", "skipped"];
```

Then use nested [array mapping functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to

1. create a new array that consists of a separate data series for each value in your `statusTypes` array; and
2. for each data series, create a version of your data array that contains the appropriate count value.

Like this:

```
var dataSeries = statusTypes.map( function(type) {

          //for each type, create a mapped version of the data array
          return data.result.map( function(d) {

                      //for each entry in the data array,
                      //create a new data object based on the 
                      //specific type of count
                      return { date: d.date,
                               count: d[type]
                             };
                 } );

    });
```

Comment: Could you use this to generate a more nested structure like this:

var layers = [
  {
    "name": "total",
    "values": [
      { "date": Sun Mar 02 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time), "count":  91},
      { "date": Mon Mar 03 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time), "count": 290}
    ]
  }
];

I'm playing around with it, but I've never used map before.

Comment: `map` just creates a new array where each element is the result of running the function on the corresponding element of the original array.  If you want each element to be an object, instead of just the sub-array, just make sure that is what is returned from the external mapping function: `function(type) { var o = {}; o.name = type; o.values = /*internal mapping function */; return o; }`